# How to set up secrets in ECS task definition for container environment variable?

Tags: amazon-ecs

I try to set up AWS ECS task definition of my docker frontend container to an AWS backend url.

In my .env.production:

REACT_APP_HOST=secrets.BACKEND_URL

how should I modify my secrets format or syntax, so that in my ECS task definition when I set container environment variable can be correctly used?
key: BACKEND_URL      value:xxxxx

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I inderstamd your use case entirely but you can save your secrets in Secrets Manager or AWS SSM parameter store and pull them in your task def

Answer (score 4):

You need to use *Secrets* block in ECS task definition, then during run time, ECS will retrieve the secret value and inject as env variable into container.

Some docs if you use with CF, CLI or TF are similar as well

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-secret.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data-secrets.html